# If value is not given in form its not storing null value defaultly?

Tags: python, django

I created a form in django.I need to set imagefield as optional so i gave required=False.And in my model i gave default = None.My problem is if the user doesn't set profile picture the default value None is not storing in database?

forms.py

```
class Register(forms.Form):
    Email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                                           {"class":"inputvalues"}))
    Username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                            {"class":"inputvalues"}))
    Password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs= 
                          ({"class":"inputvalues"})))
    Firstname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                    {"class":"inputvalues"}),max_length=30)
    Lastname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                         {"class":"inputvalues"}),max_length=40)
    Confirm_Password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs= 
                                 ({"class":"inputvalues"})))
    picture = forms.ImageField(required = False)
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media',default=None)
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Register(request.POST,request.FILES)
        pro=Profile()
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['Email']
            User_name=form.cleaned_data['Username']
            Password=form.cleaned_data['Password']
            firstname=form.cleaned_data['Firstname']
            lastname=form.cleaned_data['Lastname']
            user=User.objects.create_user(username=User_name,
                                    password=Password,email=email,
                          first_name=firstname,last_name=lastname)
            if form.cleaned_data['picture']:
                pro.image = request.FILES['picture']
                pro.user = user
                pro.save()
            redirect('/')
```

Comment: `default value None is not storing in database` what do you mean by "is not storing"? Do you get something else in this field? Do you receive an error message?

Comment: `None` means no value stored in the field. If you know the difference between null and none, then it's easier to understand. If you want to set default value `None` on db field then use `default="None"`

Comment: I gave default="None" .Its only creating a user in user model.There is nothing related to that user is stored in profile model.Its not even giving error message

Comment: You need to set `default="None"` on Profile model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pro` is not saved when no picture provided.
Try changing code to this:

```
        if form.cleaned_data['picture']:
            pro.image = request.FILES['picture']
        pro.user = user
        pro.save()
```